# Flex styles CSS using var

Tags: css, apache-flex, flex4

I am using CSS stylesheet which has multiple styles defined in it which are based on a 'baseColour' property in my Flex application.
When application load first time, this baseColour is applied to all styles correctly.

Now, what I am looking for is: If user updates this 'baseColour', then all the component styles should update themselves which are based on this 'baseColour'.

How can I achieve this? Any pointers will be helpful.
Thanks.

styles.css

```
.leftPage
{
    skinClass: ClassReference("skins.LeftPageSkin");
    themeColour: PropertyReference("baseColour");
}

.rightPage
{
    skinClass: ClassReference("skins.RightPageSkin");
    themeColour: PropertyReference("baseColour");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if StyleManager has any methods suited for this. Why are you using CSS for this and not databinding?